# Quantifier equivalence.

Tags: logic

I was wondering how to prove with natural deduction that

`∀x[¬..]:¬∃x[...]`

Is there any proof because it is obvious but  I cannot prove it

Answer (score 1):

As a non-formal yet intuitive 'proof':

A universal can be seen as kind of conjunction, that is, if $a,b,c,...$ denote the objects in your domain, then you can think of a universal like this:

$$\forall x \: P(x) \approx P(a) \land P(b) \land P(c) \land ...$$

Similarly, we can think of an existential like this:

$$\exists x \: P(x) \approx P(a) \lor P(b) \lor P(c) \lor ...$$

So:

$$\forall x \: \neg P(x) \approx \neg P(a) \land \neg P(b) \land \neg P(c) \land ... \Leftrightarrow \text{DeMorgan}$$

$$\neg (P(a) \lor\neg P(b) \lor \neg P(c) \lor ... ) \approx \neg \exists x \ P(x) $$

This is why the quantifier Negation Laws are sometimes called the 'DeMorgan Laws for Quantifiers'

If you want a formal proof, here is one made in Fitch:

[image]